# DC js : adding default values to crossfilter groups

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am using DCjs to display charts, tables and select menus based on JSON data.

There is one issue I cannot solve. In my select Menu, I want to display keys with default values even when they do not exist in the corresponding group. Values would be set to O, just to show that the value option exists and is considered.

I explored many ways but unsuccessfully. Generally, how can we add default values to a group ?

Comment: read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't see the problem with this question. Not every question has to include code, does it? That said, [this question is in the dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#ensure-that-bins-exist-even-if-there-are-no-values-in-them). Advice: don't add broad tags to your questions, that will only attract close votes. (I'm removing them.)

Comment: Yes for a first time I did not do it well.. Ok thank you for the link.